# What is actually contained in my JSPM produced bundle

Tags: angular, jspm

I have been using Angular2 recently. It is great and I can put stuff together pretty quick but I just can't get my head around how to actually get my builds from dev to live. I have read article after article but there are so many different approaches, set-ups and preferred tools that its hard to find a good starting point without a load of prior knowledge. So, I wonder if someone can put a few things straight for me.

I've gone back to the [5 Minute Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and added `JSPM` locally as well. I run...

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/main www/bundle.js
```

...and get a monster javascript file in my `www` folder and here my questions start:

**What has actually been bundled up in that file?**
Is it only the components etc that I have written - in this case just `main` and
    `app.component` - or have other dependencies gone into the mix as well?

**How do I use the bundle?**
Assuming I take the existing [index.html](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/index.html) as a starting point and add `<script src='www/bundle.js'></script>` what do I now need to remove/add/amend from that HTML to be able to push `index.html` and bundle.js` to server and have them run as my app?

I apologise for asking a rather general question but I'm surrounded by designers at work and StackOverflow is my only target for questions. In my defence I have read A LOT on this and tried many different seed projects and approaches but there is always some error with some dependency or script or depricated this that or the other. I assume that with Angular2 still being in beta this is going to be the case and so I just wanted to look at the simplest case possible. I know I could use this-task-runner to do X and that-reloader to do Y but all I want at the moment is to understand the basics of going from dev to live with the simplest build possible.

Thank you so much for answers, part answers, links etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

JSPM is built upon [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) which enables dynamic module loading. It is a planned native feature in a future version of the JavaScript language. It's only in draft form at this time. Once it's implemented, we won't need System.js anymore.

So, to answer your question, everything that enables this dynamic module loading and its dependencies is included within your `bundle.js` file along with your app code. For production, you only need to upload this file and probably Angular (but I'd link to it's CDN). You may want to uglify it first to minimize its size. I'm not positive JSPM does this for you. I typically use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for minification and other tasks.

When in doubt, read the [docs](http://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html).